# How to update time in mysql by ADDTIME()?

Tags: mysql

I have table: test and field called: id. I want update time (ex. add 2 hours) where id=1000. How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE test SET time = time + INTERVAL 2 HOUR WHERE id = 1000
```

Using [`ADDTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime):

```
UPDATE test SET time = ADDTIME(time, '02:00:00') WHERE id = 1000
```